# Can't edit environment file with sudo inside Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ubuntu

I have a docker container which is builded on `ubuntu:bionic`. In this container, I want to install java and set `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables. Here is how I did:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
USER root
RUN adduser --disabled-password kafka-ui
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo git apt-utils
ADD /sudoers.txt /etc/sudoers
RUN chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
USER kafka-ui
```

sudoers.txt

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
kafka-ui ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk git

sudo echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/" >> /etc/environment
sudo echo "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> /etc/environment
source /etc/environment
```

In the 6th and 7th lines of `entrypoint.sh` file, I got `/entrypoint.sh: line 6: /etc/environment: Permission denied` even though I used `sudo`. What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How come your not installing java in the Dockerfile? 
I mean doing it like this it will install Java every time you start the container, do you want that?

In case that's not a requirement you can install java in the Dockerfile and then use

```
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
```

In case this is not acceptable, try to 'debug' by bashing into the container and execute those commands manually